# Agora UE5 Android build Failed to extract native libraries for ARM64

Tags: android, sdk, libraries, agora.io, unreal-engine5

I'm trying to use Agora with UE5 to build for Android devices, when trying to build for Windows it works properly.

But for Android:
I get the failed: [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113] error when building for Android device.
[image]
Any way to fix this?

I made sure to uncomment this line in Agora.Build.cs: string Architecture = "arm64-v8a" to build for the arm64 architecture, when trying to build and compile the app it compiles successfully, it creates 2 files:
-AFS_Agora_Unreal_Video-Android-Shipping-arm64.apk
-Agora_Unreal_Video-Android-Shipping-arm64.apk
the AFS...apk gets installed on my device without an issue, but not the case for the other .apk file.
However when launching the installed AFS...apk app it's stuck on the splash screen forever.

I also get this warning at the start:
[image]
Is there perhaps something to change in the APL_armv7 ? because in Agora.Build.cs: I uncommented this line: string Architecture = "arm64-v8a"; to support the arm64 architecture

Comment: Please don't post terminal output in screen shots, those images are difficult to read, just copy and paste the code into your question and format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

for your problem I think Agora development team didn't support arm64 and uncommenting the line in Agora.Build.cs: string Architecture = "arm64-v8a" won't help, I think submitting a ticket for them would be the best solution. I hope you've solved it by now.
I read that you have build the project for Windows and it worked properly on UE5. did you test opening the camera without any crashes ? if yes, can you tell which template project you used and the plugin version? I have been trying for two days with no luck at all.

[Link to My Issue in details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72596102/how-to-solve-ue5-crashing-after-enabling-agora-plugin-and-opening-video-feed)

Thanks